# Run code once add-ins have finished loading

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016, excel-addins

I have code under workbook_open procedure.
At the beginning of this code a userform (loading screen) initiates whilst the remainder of the code runs to hide/unhide sheets for the respective user.

The userform closes at the end of this code however, this means that it closes before addins have loaded.

Is there a way for me to code:
Once addins have loaded, close userform?

I attempted the Wait function however this doesn't work, this just delays the userform closing and therefore delays the addins being loaded.

Comment: How about having these processes in separate procedures/functions, so that VBA is forced to complete them before going to the next task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your code currently in Workbook_Open to a separate "ContinueOpen" subroutine in a normal module. Then call this new routine from Workbook_Open, using Application.OnTime:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.OnTime Now, "'" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & "'!ContinueOpen"
End Sub
```

Comment: This has worked brilliantly!

Thank you very much jkpieterse!